# How did ancient China invent such wonders as fear systems and calendar before ancient Europe?

Tags: ancient-china

What were some methods Chinese used to come up with such amazing creations like paper, compass, clocks, steel with chrome for keeping the blade from rusting etc.

- What were their "scientific methods?"
- Is it the same as today but they use it just way before most?

Comment: It might be worth looking in [Josephs Needhams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Needham#Science_and_Civilisation_in_China) *Science & Civilisation* in China.

Comment: @congusbongus: that question was put on *hold* as being too broad?

Comment: I think the Babylonians, Egyptians, and perhaps Indians may have beaten the Chinese & Europeans to a lot of that.

Comment: I've voted to re-open the question as the duplicate referred to (I see the link has now been deleted) had a single inadequate answer - it had been voted down (-1).

Comment: @MoziburUllah - Its also on hold, due to being far too broad. However, if this question is an "exact duplicate" of a question that is too broad...

Comment: The question of which this has been marked as a duplicate has itself been deleted and appears as 404 Page Not Found to most. Perhaps this question should either be re-opened or closed for another reason?

Comment: @T.E.D.  The question is essential "why civilization centers have been born here (China, Egypt, wherever) and not there (bog lands of Northern Europe)?". In that sense, the question is answerable.

Comment: @Greg - The issue isn't "Is this answerable" so much as "Is this *objectively* answerable within the space bounds of a reasonably-sized SE post?"

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, I think it is objectively answerable why civilizations like China, Mesopotamia, Egypt emerged early or what kind of technological development they had e.g. compared to Europe. Or how our knowledge is limited on early  European cultures (eg Varna). Or how the question is partially based on misinformation and propaganda (e.g Greek mechanical clocks are 1000 years older than the Chinese ones, papyrus 1-2 milenia older than paper, optical based were widespread in Europe before the magnetic were invented in China).

Comment: @Greg: There's also the question of whether we're discussing purely European culture, or the Mesopotamian, Egyptian, Greek & Roman Mediterranean culture that was ancestor to it.  Then there's the Celtic/Gallic culture that the Romans pretty much obliterated, and whatever predecessors of theirs that were responsible for Stonehenge and all the other ancient monuments that litter Europe.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, these are all legitimate points.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what exactly is a "fear system"?  Google thinks it's either something to do with psychology/physiology, or an acronym for something to do with computer gaming.